# Onclick functions, innerHTMLs and creating tables

Tags: javascript, html

So here's the code:

```js
window.onload=function(e){
//Created by Firestar001
 var X;
 var Y;
 
 var board="";
 
 var rizzalt=document.getElementById("rezzalt");
 
 var letters = new Array;
 letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"];
 
 for(a=0; a<=9; a++){
 board+="<tr>";
  for(b=1;b<=14; b++)
 {
  board+="<td id=/'"+ letters[a] +  b +"/' onClick=/'AreaCode()/'>" + letters[a]+b+"</td>";
 }
 board+="</tr>";
 }
 
 var Grade = document.getElementById('friend_water');
 Grade.innerHTML = board;
 }
 function AreaCode(){
 console.log("I work");
      rizzalt.innerHTML+="Works ";
 }
```

```html
<table id="friend_water" border="1 solid black">jklol</table><p></p><p id="rezzalt"></p>
```

I've included the "rizzalt rezzalt" in there to provide a confirmation while using the code snippit thing on stackoverflow.

So it'll create a battleship grid, A-J, 1-14.  What I want to happen is when a player clicks on a square (ex: C4), I want the console to say "I work" so.... I know it works.  The table loads properly but when I click on a cell it gives me:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Referencing to line 1 in the html which is the `<!DOCTYPE html>` line.

Thank you all for your help.

EDIT: SOLVED.

Thank you again all for your help.  The code properly works and now I can get to work on more of my Battleship game.

Comment: This really needs a different title. The current one describes nothing about what the issue is, and won't be found by others who are experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Got an idea as to what the title should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this modified version of your code

```js
var rizzalt=document.getElementById("rezzalt");
window.onload=function(e){
//Created by Firestar001
 var X;
 var Y;
 
 var board="";
 
 
 
 var letters = new Array;
 letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"];
 
 for(a=0; a<=9; a++){
 board+="<tr>";
  for(b=1;b<=14; b++)
 {
  board+="<td id='"+ letters[a] +  b +"' onClick='AreaCode()'>" + letters[a]+b+"</td>";
 }
 board+="</tr>";
 }
 
 var Grade = document.getElementById('friend_water');
 Grade.innerHTML = board;
 }
 function AreaCode(){
 console.log("I work");
      rezzalt.innerHTML+="Works ";
 }
```

```html
<table id="friend_water" border="1 solid black">jklol</table><p></p><p id="rezzalt"></p>
```

Comment: So it seems I'd use "' '" to keep the quotations from mis-interpreting what's code and what's text.  (Sorry if this doesn't make sense.)

Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Just thought I'd comment on it in case someone else was looking at this so they won't be like "What's the difference?"

Comment: when you use different type of quotations like " and ', you don't have to add escape character (there is no difference which one is outer or inner).But when you use same type you should add escape character before inner one like board+="<td id=\""+ letters[a] +  b +"\" onClick=\"AreaCode()\">". and be aware to use same type.

Answer (score 0):

Your escape character is wrong.  It should be `\`, not `/`

```js
window.onload=function(e){
//Created by Firestar001
 var X;
 var Y;
 
 var board="";
 
 var rizzalt=document.getElementById("rezzalt");
 
 var letters = new Array;
 letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"];
 
 for(a=0; a<=9; a++){
 board+="<tr>";
  for(b=1;b<=14; b++)
 {
       //error was below.  all escape slashes were the wrong slash.
  board+="<td id=\'"+ letters[a] +  b +"\' onClick=\'AreaCode()\'>" + letters[a]+b+"</td>";
 }
 board+="</tr>";
 }
 
 var Grade = document.getElementById('friend_water');
 Grade.innerHTML = board;
 }
 function AreaCode(){
 console.log("I work");
      rizzalt.innerHTML+="Works ";
 }
```

```html
<table id="friend_water" border="1 solid black">jklol</table><p></p><p id="rezzalt"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
board+='<td id="' + letters[a] +  b + '" onClick="AreaCode()">' + letters[a]+b+'</td>';
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why this code answers the asker's question.